# Ajax inhibits rendering html

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Currently I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC Application. I want to do an advanced search. There is a Javascript function, which builds a dictionary from the available fields. Afterwards I pass the dict via ajax post to a a controller Method

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                url: "@Url.Action("OnSearchButtonClicked", "Suche")"
            });
```

The Controller Method which is called looks like the following:

```
public ActionResult OnSearchButtonClicked(Dictionary<string, string> stepsDictionary) {
        List<zData> results = sr.AdvancedSearch(stepsDictionary);
        return View("Results", results);
    }
```

The problem is that the View won't get rendered. I already know that I can pass the produced html to a success function inside ajax like:

```
success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
```

But how can I inhibit the ajax success call and instead let the controller render the view? Is this even possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't POST the advanced search data to a controller method instead of using ajax?

Comment: No just using post didn't work, because I have a dropdown field with categories and depending of what is chosen, there dynamically appear fields for the attributes of the chosen type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how can I inhibit the ajax success call and instead let the
>   controller render the view? Is this even possible?

Yes it is possible. Use [Ajax.BeginForm() in correlation with RenderPartial](http://singulartechnologies.com/asp-net-mvc-ajax-beginform-sample-code).

Or else you might have to do what you are doing right now, but get the AJAX Success Function populate a div on the view with the HTML result.

Comment: Thank you very much. The partial view way is working :)